# JavaScript addEventListener to add a textbox on a click?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I need to be able to click on some text (id="txt") and fire an event which replaces that text with a textbox; currently I have this code:

```
var myTxt = document.getElementById("txt");
myTxt.addEventListener("click", name1Click, false);

function textclick()
{
    var removeMe = document.getElementById("txt");
    var root = document.body;
    root.removeChild(removeMe);
    var addMe = document.createElement("input");
    addMe.setAttribute("type","text");
    addMe.setAttribute("id","i");
    root.appendChild(addMe);
}
```

This is not working, however, any ideas?

Comment: Please show us the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you have posted here, your eventListener is calling `name1Click`, but your function is named `textclick`.

When you fix that, it seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/55mQq/.

You may want to note that `addEventListener()` is not supported in older versions of IE (you have to use `attachEvent()` instead).

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
> var myTxt = document.getElementById("txt");
> myTxt.addEventListener("click", name1Click, false);
```

You are adding a function named *name1Click* in *addEventListener*, but your function is called *textclick*. Fix that and it "works"

Also:

```
> function textclick() {
>     var removeMe = document.getElementById("txt");
>     var root = document.body;
>     root.removeChild(removeMe);
```

It is likely that the *removeMe* element won't always be a child of the body, so you can remove it more generically with:

```
  removeMe.parentNode.removeChild(removeMe);
```

But the node can be replaced rather than removed, see below.

```
>     var addMe = document.createElement("input");
>     addMe.setAttribute("type","text");
>     addMe.setAttribute("id","i");
```

The *setAttribute* method is buggy in some browsers and better avoided if not needed. For standard DOM properties, just set the property directly:

```
    addMe.type = 'text';
    addMe.id = 'i';

>     root.appendChild(addMe);
```

Rather than removing one node and inserting another, you can just use one operation and replace the first one generically:

```
  removeMe.parentNode.replaceChild(addMe, removeMe);

> }
```